# pandas dataframe manipulation without using loop

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Please find the below input and output. Corresponding to each store id and period id , 11 Items should be present , if any item is missing, add it and fill that row with 0
**without using loop**.

Any help is highly appreciated.

**input**

[image]

**Expected Output**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```py
from itertools import product

pdindex=product(df.groupby(["store_id", "period_id"]).groups, range(1,12))

pdindex=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(map(lambda x: (*x[0], x[1]), pdindex), names=["store_id", "period_id", "Item"])

df=df.set_index(["store_id", "period_id", "Item"])

res=pd.DataFrame(index=pdindex, columns=df.columns)

res.loc[df.index, df.columns]=df

res=res.fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Now this will work only assuming you don't have any `Item` outside of range `[1,11]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

**Sample df**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'store_id':[1160962,1160962,1160962,1160962,1160962,1160962,1160962,1160962,1160962,1160962, 1160962],
                   'period_id':[1025,1025,1025,1025,1025,1025,1026,1026,1026,1026,1026],
                   'item_x':[1,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,5,6,7],
                  'z':[1,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,5,6,7]})
```

**Solution:**

```
num = range(1,12)
def f(x):
    return x.reindex(num, fill_value=0)\
                   .assign(store_id=x['store_id'].mode()[0], period_id = x['period_id'].mode()[0])

df.set_index('item_x').groupby(['store_id','period_id'], group_keys=False).apply(f).reset_index()
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work correctly, the `item_x` values for the first period are respected, but on the second period are not (are copied from the first.) It seems to me that using reindex on a groupby might be the source of the issue...

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplification of @GrzegorzSkibinski's correct answer.

This answer is not modifying the original DataFrame. It uses fewer variables to store intermediate data structures and employs a list comprehension to simplify an use of map.

I'm also using `reindex()` rather than creating a new DataFrame using the generated index and populating it with the original data.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

df.set_index(
    ["store_id", "period_id", "Item_x"]
).reindex(
    pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
        group + (item,)
        for group, item in itertools.product(
            df.groupby(["store_id", "period_id"]).groups, 
            range(1, 12),
        )],
        names=["store_id", "period_id", "Item_x"]
    ),
    fill_value=0,
).reset_index()
```

In testing, output matched what you listed as expected.